# Is there a way to detect a barcode format from Laser led barcode scanner and not from camera

Tags: ionic-framework, barcode

the scanner detects the barcode string but not the format (EAN_8,  EAN_13)

i use ionic 4 and building for android devices

i need to know the barcode format from the scanner that uses Laser ligth, the barcodescanner ionic native plugin only uses the camera, which is not my case.

Comment: you need to checkout the bar-code scanner manufacturer for this

Answer (score 0):

Many laser scanners default to not transmitting the barcode format referred to as a Code ID. However there is often an option that allows you to prepend or append a character representing the Code ID scanned. For example on page 13-3 of the [LS2208 Product Reference Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/ls2208-product-reference-guide-en-us.pdf), you will find three configuration barcodes that will enable most Symbol scanners to add characters to the beginning of the barcode string.

For the particular use case cited, you would want your scanner to be set for AIM Code ID and expect a string of "]E0" to precede a string from a EAN 13 symbol and a string of "]E4" to precede a EAN 8 symbol.